# Usage of "CALL" function | Batch

Tags: batch-file, call

I am a simpleman, so if this could be kept as dumbed-down as possible, that would be great
Onto the problem

```
@echo off
goto preparation

:damageCalculator
set /a damage=(((((2 * %level% / 5) + 2) * %attackStat% * %attackPower% / %opponentDefenceStat%) / 50) + 2)
set /a opponentHealth-=%damage%
echo %opponentHealth%
pause>nul

:preparation
set /a level=25
set /a attackStat=35
set /a attackPower=75
set /a opponentDefenceStat=46
set /a opponentHealth=350

:attack
call :damageCalculator
echo It did %damage% damage!!
pause>nul
```

The problem is that the "CALL" acts as a goto and I'm stuck in and endless loop
I'm sure I've not set it up correctly
Please show me the countless things that I've done wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a

```
goto :eof
```

to exit from the sub-routine and return to the calling part of the batch file.

```
:damageCalculator
  set /a damage=(((((2 * %level% / 5) + 2) * %attackStat% * %attackPower% / %opponentDefenceStat%) / 50) + 2)
  set /a opponentHealth-=%damage%
  echo %opponentHealth%
  pause>nul

  goto :eof
```

Comment: I'm surprised I was only off by one line